# Cant boot instance from snapshot created from boot disk of another VM

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine

I am unable to boot a new instance from snapshot created from boot disk of another VM. In the serial port, I can see the following message.

```
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced
```

I tried to create a new disk from this snapshot and attach it as a secondary storage to a new VM and ran fsck command. This is the output

```
 fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdb1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 576 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 1299 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 1990 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 6308 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 6322 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
...
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry 'localhost.2016-06-29.log' in /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/logs (6816365) has deleted/unused inode 6815859.  Clear? yes
Entry 'catalina.2016-06-29.log' in /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/logs (6816365) has deleted/unused inode 6815858.  Clear? yes
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Unattached zero-length inode 576.  Clear? yes
Unattached zero-length inode 1012.  Clear? yes
Unattached inode 1299
Connect to /lost+found? yes
Inode 1299 ref count is 65535, should be 1.  Fix? yes
Unattached inode 1990
Connect to /lost+found? yes
...
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(33413--33415) -(33423--33427) -33429 -(33431--...
Free inodes count wrong for group #832 (7066, counted=7068).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong (32653808, counted=32653867).
Fix? yes
/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
```

Now my question is, can I keep using the original machine ? I am afraid that if the original machine restarts it will get stuck during boot. 
If I want to run fsck on it, how do I do it without instance downtime ?
What would be the root cause of such issue ?

Comment: Two clarifying questions: Which steps did you use to create the snapshot? And are you currently able to log in on the running VM?

Comment: I clicked on the running instance's boot disk and clicked on the "Create snapshot" button. Yes, I am able to log into the running instance.

Comment: I would check if the running instance has any problems reading the files mentioned in the fsck output. I would also look in the log of the running instance for any indications of file system problems.

Comment: For future snapshots creation it is recommended to sync your file system to flush the disk buffers before you create a snapshot. The detailed steps are documented under [Prepare the persistent disk for a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#prepare_the_persistent_disk_for_a_snapshot)

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.